# Problem about completeness

Tags: metric-spaces

Does there exist a complete metric on $(0,1)$ inducing the usual topology?

My problem is that I cant understand what will I have to do to answer the question.It's a problem of a competitive exam.

Comment: Do you know a complete metric space that is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$?

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb R$ is complete iff it is closed.Is it possible to find so?Please correct me if I sound wrong.I have just started completeness.

Comment: Consider $d(x,y)= \left|\tan(\pi(x-\frac12))-\tan(\pi(y-\frac12))\right|$. And how did I come up with this?

Comment: Note that completeness is not a topological property, it is a metric [more generally, uniform] property. While a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is complete _in the induced metric_ if and only if it is closed, subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ can be complete in other metrics inducing the topology without being closed. In fact, every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is completely metrisable.

Comment: Exactly I was going to ask this please explain @HagenvonEitzen sir

Comment: @learnmore: A subset of $\Bbb R$ is complete *under the standard metric* iff it is closed. But here the problem is asking to change the metric.

Comment: Can anyone please help me to interpret the problem in simpler terms

Answer (score 0):

The usual topology on $(0,1)$ just happens to give a space which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, the reals. So, let's use this fact. Let $f\colon (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a homeomorphism and let $d\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the usual metric on the reals. Let's then define a metric $\delta\colon (0,1)\times(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$\delta(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y)).$$ Prove that $\delta$ induces the usual topology on $(0,1)$ by using the fact that $f$ is a homeomorphism and $d$ induces the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What to show to prove $\delta $ induces usual topology any hints

Comment: Show that an open ball in $((0,1),\delta)$ is an interval $(a,b)$ with $0\leq a<b\leq 1$. Hint: the preimage of an open ball in $(0,1)$ under $f^{-1}$ will also be an open interval (possibly infinite if $a=0$ or $b=1$), and $f$ is necessarily monotonic.